# Embeddable 3rd party web tools security against stealing the key

Tags: html, browser, secret-key

We are building a website and we are using plenty of third-party tools that basically give you an HTML script tag and ask you to place it into your index.html. A few examples of such tools are:

- Google Analytics
- Google Maps
- Zendesk Web Widget

Usually, such tools give you some sort of key that identifies with your account. But that key is publicly visible to every visitor of the website as it is hardcoded into the HTML.

Therefore I was wondering, whether there are any protections against malicious users getting my key and using it for bad purposes, e.g.

- spamming my Zendesk inbox.
- spamming my Google Analytics with fake data, that is indistinguishable from real user data.
- using up the whole of my Google Maps query quota by reusing the same key in their website.

I haven't tested all of the scenarios, but e.g. Zendesk works on our dev/test environments out of the box, suggesting that this could be an issue.

Comment: One solution: Stop using the services, or at least the snippets. But I know... clients love them tools, and bragging about the visitor count shown in Analytics can be entertaining :D I would love a solution for this as we have these problems too..

Answer (score 0):

Since the problems with Google Analytics and fake data had been the biggest pain in our ass, we have been trying some stuff.

Add the (spam)domains to a htaccess and prevent access to the website:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} net-profits\.xyz [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} social-widget\.xyz [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} share-buttons\.xyz [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} free-traffic\.xyz [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} traffic2cash\.xyz [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} website-analyzer.info\.xyz [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} semalt\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} buttons-for-website\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} make-money-online\.7makemoneyonline\.com
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

This kept them away. Maybe you'll have more, or other domains. I think there is an OpenSource list on GitHub somewhere that is a maintained list.

Probably you could block all referers ending with xyz or xxx (and other exotic domains), as long as you are sure there aren't any you KNOW that link to your site in a legit way.

I've done some reading and  maybe we can't solve all:
https://medium.com/@gajus/do-not-protect-your-website-from-scraping-part-1-technology-barriers-b0ced398d16d